# Django Class view - only display if column 'admin' contains 1

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have been working on extending the following project: [jquery file upload form](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload%60) & i want to only display items from the database that have the value 1 in a column called admin.

Can someone tell me how to modify the following class based view to only display images that adhere to the above requirements?

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        data = [{'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'thumbnail_url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'delete_url': reverse('upload-delete', args=[self.object.id]), 'delete_type': "DELETE"}]
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pictures'] = Picture.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: which model has the admin field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a very basic Django question and I would recommend you learn how it works.

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        f = self.request.FILES.get('file')
        data = [{'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'thumbnail_url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'delete_url': reverse('upload-delete', args=[self.object.id]), 'delete_type': "DELETE"}]
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PictureCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Change the all to some filter
        context['pictures'] = Picture.objects.filter(admin=1)
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it would be that simple, sorry.